# Redis or Ehcache?

Tags: spring, caching, redis, spring-boot, ehcache

Which is better suited for the following environment:

1. Persistence not a compulsion.
2. Multiple servers (with Ehcache some cache sync must be required).
3. Infrequent writes and frequent reads.
4. Relatively small database (very less memory requirement).

I will pour out what's in my head currently. I may be wrong about these.

I know Redis requires a separate server (?) and Ehcache provides local cache so it must be faster but will replicate cache across servers (?). Updating all caches after some update on one is possible with Ehcache.

My question is which will suit better for the environment I mentioned?
Whose performance will be better or what are scenarios when one may outperform another?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a bit of explaination??

Comment: from (java//spring) developer perspective, it is much more easy to implement

Comment: any idea which is better performance wise??

Comment: you should think about performance when you got a performance issue..not now

Comment: You Can think of Redis as your Cache implementation, as it has distributed nature while using Amazon's ElastiCache, its a better choice for developers for making caching server for the application infrastructure

Comment: Here an article that may give some information about the performance of Ehcache and Redis (plus other caching solutions):
[Evaluation of Caching Frameworks](https://blog.nomissolutions.com/labs/2015/03/10/evaluation-of-caching-frameworks/)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can think Redis as a **shared data structure**, while Ehcache is a *memory block* storing serialized data objects. This is the main difference.

Redis as a *shared data structure* means you can put some **predefined** data structure (such as *String*, *List*, *Set* [etc](https://redis.io/topics/data-types)) in one language and retrieve it in another language. This is useful if your project is **multilingual**, for example: Java the backend side , and PHP the front side. You can use Redis for a shared cache. But it can only store predefined data structure, you cannot insert any Java objects you want.

If your project is only Java, i.e. not **multilingual**, Ehcache is a convenient solution.

Comment: Yes but I can always serialize java objects into JSON strings and store in redis. I believe that's the way most people use redis as a cache.

Comment: Is it really worth if my data never grows beyond 100 or 200MB max where I don't want to distribute data across clusters. If my data is limited(max 200MB). Is redis a good choice then? Is EhCache better than Redis in that case?

Comment: Which one will have a better performance?

Answer (score 12):

You will meet issues with EhCache scaling and need resources to manage it during failover and etc.
**Redis benefits** over EhCache:

1. It uses time proven gossip protocol for Node discovery and synchronization.
2. Availability of fully managed services like [AWS ElastiCache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/WhatIs.html), [Azure Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/). Such services offers full automation, support and management of Redis, so developers can focus on their applications and not maintaining their databases.
3. Correct large memory amount handling (we all know that Redis can manage with hundreds of gigabytes of RAM on single machine). It doesn't have problems with Garbage collection like Java.

And finally existence of Java Developer friendly Redis client - [Redisson](https://redisson.org).
Redisson provides many Java friendly objects **on top of Redis**, like:

- Set
- ConcurrentMap
- List
- Queue
- Deque
- BlockingQueue
- BlockingDeque
- ReadWriteLock
- Semaphore
- Lock
- AtomicLong
- CountDownLatch
- Publish / Subscribe
- ExecutorService
- and many more...

Redisson supports **local cache** for Map structure which cold give you **45x** performance boost for read operations.

Here is [the article](https://redisson.org/feature-comparison-redis-vs-ehcache.html) describing detailed feature comparison of Ehcache and Redis.

Comment: I ended up using redis and later switched to hazelcast (I find redisson similar to hazelcast though - support of java friendly objects etc). I''ll consider using redission in future projects :)